# how to take numpy array as an input in logistic regression?

Tags: numpy, logistic-regression, one-hot-encoding

Currently i'm working on a video recommendation system which will predicts a video in a form of 0 (Negative) and 1 (positive). I successfully scrape data set from YouTube and also find sentiments of YouTube comments in the form of 0 (Negative) and 1 (positive).I encode text data of my csv using one hot encoder and get output in the form of numpy array. Now My question is how to give the numpy array as an input  (X) in logistic regression ? Below are my code, output and csv(1874 X 2).

Target variable is `Comments_Sentiments`

[image: csv]

```
#OneHotEncoding
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from sklearn import preprocessing

X = pd.read_csv("C:/Users/Shahnawaz Irfan/Desktop/USIrancrisis/demo.csv")
#X.head(5)

X = X.select_dtypes(include=[object])
#X.head(5)

#X.shape

#X.columns

le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()

X_2 = X.apply(le.fit_transform)
X_2.head()

enc = preprocessing.OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(X_2)

onehotlabels = enc.transform(X_2).toarray()
onehotlabels.shape

onehotlabels
```

Output is:

```
array([[1.],
   [1.],
   [1.],
   ...,
   [1.],
   [1.],
   [1.]])
```

Can any one resolve this query by taking this numpy array as an input in logistic regression?

Answer (score 0):

you can use the inverse function`enc.inverse_transform([[0, 1, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1, 0]])` `enc.fit([[0, 0, 3], [1, 1, 0], [0, 2, 1], [1, 0, 2]])`

Comment: ok i use `inverse_transform` method but can i use `onehotlabels` variable as a parameter? because output store  in `onehotlabels` variable